# Use "NOT IN" in FileNet queries

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet

If I want to restrict the value of a metadata to a subset, I would do something on the line of standard SQL synthax ("`IN`" operator):

```
SELECT This, ID from MyClass WHERE MyMetadata IN ('AAA', 'BBB')
```

But how can I do the opposite, so obtaining all the results for which the metadata value is not in the subset?

By using the standard "`NOT IN`" operator:

```
SELECT This, ID from MyClass WHERE MyMetadata NOT IN ('AAA', 'BBB')
```

I obtain a synthax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileNet SQL synthax is a bit different, and the `NOT` operator should be placed before. Like this:

```
SELECT This, ID from MyClass WHERE NOT (MyMetadata IN ('AAA', 'BBB'))
```